# Let's settle with each other

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, verbs

How to ask someone who owes you some amount money to settle with you in everyday speech?

> - Hey Brian, we'll talk about further problems. But you owe me 4000 dollars. If you don't mind, let's....................
>
> a. settle with each other first. [it strikes me as the most natural based on what I say.] 
>   b. settle our balance first. 
>   c. settle out account first.

I have looked up in several dictionaries, but was unable to find a source that could provide me with my needed information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say "let's settle up first" in that context - see https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/settle-up

Comment: I know the phrasal verb settle up @Andy J. Then please let me know how this verb can be used in another example like: "I settled up my outstanding balance with the company yesterday and left there."? Don't you think "settle one's balance with someone else" is a better choice or you can rewrite it somehow using "settle up"?

Comment: @A-friend I am a native speaker, so I might not be able to give proper reasons for my thoughts. "I settled my outstanding balance with the company" is a better choice. I think 'settle up' is intransitive - you can 'settle up _with_ a colleague' but not 'settle up a debt'.

Comment: AFAIC @Andy J, you settle up with someone and just settle a doubt with someone else. Right?

Comment: @A-friend That's right. In your example, because you remind Brian that he owes you the money, it's obvious that 'settle up' means settle this particular debt. You might say "I'll settle my debt with Michael before buying any christmas presents"

Comment: Thank you very much @Andy J. Another upvote for the prompt and to the point response which is much appreciated.

Answer (score -3):

I'm not a native speaker, there is that. Now what I and in my opinion most people would say is "let's settle with each other first". But you have mentioned settle our accounts and balance,  to me it feels too blunt I would say. To settle our affairs is also used. On a side note, in real life situation one wouldn't use $4000 but 4Grand.

Comment: Thank you; may ask you to provide us with some sources for your suggestions please?